# SQL Oracle: Find workers who done best with specific product targets

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 11g.
I have a table containing employees, products, production targets and each employee highest production of each product. Below is an example of 1 employee.

| Employee | Product | Target | Produced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Billy | A | 30 | 70 |
| Billy | B | 20 | 50 |
| Billy | C | 30 | 80 |
| Billy | D | 60 | 80 |
| John | A | 30 | 50 |
| John | B | 30 | 70 |
| John | C | 30 | 80 |
| John | D | 30 | 40 |
| John | E | 30 | 20 |
| John | F | 30 | 10 |

I need to find Employees with highest Produces while sum of targets = 90.
As a result I need to display Employee and Product.

List contain lots of employees, about 10000 products, and number of products can vary. One employee can have 3 and other can have 10

We can have a case where employee have 5 products A,B,C,D,E. All of them are Target 30. To get 90 we need to find 3. Them 3 must be the ones with the highest Produced.

Based on above table. Result expected would be:
Employee: Billy, Product C and D (sum of those products give 90 but C Produced is higher then A)

Result table:

| Employee | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Billy | C |
| Billy | D |
| John | A |
| John | B |
| John | C |

I have been trying to get my head around that for a day now. Any idea?
This can be done either as a package, procedure or a query I will build other stuff around.

Comment: Is the Product list static and relatively small? Like can it be assumed that you've only got four products A,B,C,D?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for a quick reply. List contain about 10000 products, and number of products can vary. One employee can have 3 and other can have 10.

Comment: Also, are you only concerned about two term sums? Or if B,C,D all equal 30 (sum to 90) does that satifsy your condition?

Comment: Oof, that's going to be a lot of combinations.

Comment: We can have a case where employee have 5 products A,B,C,D,E. All of them are Target 30. To get 90 we need to find 3. Them 3 must be the ones with the highest Produced.

Comment: Wow! My head is hurting too. Can you [edit] your question please, to incorporate your comments about # of records, etc.  And also to add a little more sample table data for maybe another employee, and add separate tables showing expected results for each particular employee.

Comment: It would be really, _really_ helpful if you would formatted text code of your table's DDL and INSERTS of representative data.  That way people could copy that and create their own tests to work with.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example